# Apache Beam - Fire one window at a time

Tags: python, etl, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm trying to use Apache Beam to create a pipeline that -

1. Reads messages from a stream
2. Groups the messages by some id
3. Appends the message to a file with a corresponding id

The append operation is not atomic - it's composed of reading the file's content, appending the new messages in memory, and overriding the file with the new content. I'm using fixed windowing, and I noticed that sometimes I have two consecutive windows that are fired together which causes a race with writing the file.

A way to reproduce this behavior is to use FixedWindows(5) (fixed window of 5 seconds) with AfterProcessingTime(20) which causes a window to be fired only every 20 seconds. So, 4 windows contained in this 20 seconds period will be fired together. For example, look at the following code -

```
pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(
    streaming=True
)

with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    class SleepAndCon(beam.DoFn):
        def process(self, element, timestamp=beam.DoFn.TimestampParam, window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam):
            window_start = str(window.start.to_utc_datetime()).split()[1]
            window_end = str(window.end.to_utc_datetime()).split()[1]
            timestamp = str(timestamp.to_utc_datetime()).split()[1]
            curr_time = str(datetime.utcnow()).split()[1].split(".")[0]
            print(f"sleep_and_con {curr_time}-{timestamp}-{window_start}-{window_end}")

            return [element]
    
    def print_end(e):
        print("end")

    (p 
        | beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription="...")
        | beam.Map(lambda x: ('a', x))
        | beam.WindowInto(
            window.FixedWindows(5),
            trigger=Repeatedly(AfterProcessingTime(20)),
            accumulation_mode=False
        )
        | beam.GroupByKey()
        | beam.ParDo(SleepAndCon())
        | beam.Map(print_end)
    )
```

After running and sending 5 messages every 5 seconds, we got the following output:

```
sleep_and_con 13:58:19-13:57:39.999999-13:57:35-13:57:40
sleep_and_con 13:58:19-13:57:44.999999-13:57:40-13:57:45
sleep_and_con 13:58:19-13:57:49.999999-13:57:45-13:57:50
sleep_and_con 13:58:19-13:57:54.999999-13:57:50-13:57:55
sleep_and_con 13:58:19-13:57:59.999999-13:57:55-13:58:00
end
end
end
end
end
```

But this behavior happens to me also without the AfterProcessingTime trigger, randomly (I didn't manage to understand when exactly it happens)

My question is - is there a way to block a window trigger until a previous window finishes the pipeline ?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share a code snippet please ?

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements and which [Beam Pipeline Runner](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/beam-overview/) are you using?